# Reading comma separated tuples from a file in python

Tags: python, file, input

I am trying to read from a file with several tuples separated by commas. A sample input file looks like:

> (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (-1, -1), (0, -2), (1, -1), (-1, -3),
>
> (-1, 1), (-1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 3),
>
> (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 4), (5, 5), (7, 5)

After reading from this file, I need a tuple like this:

```
G = ((0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (-1, -1), (0, -2), (1, -1), (-1, -3), \
(-1, 1), (-1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 3), \
(2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 4), (5, 5), (7, 5))
```

How this can be done efficiently? Regards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since they look like proper python tuples you can use `literal_eval`. Its fast as safe:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>   Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>   and None.

```
import ast
s = '''(0, 0), (0, 2), ...'''
result = ast.literal_eval('({0})'.format(s))
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants a tuple, not list.  Is there a reason you use `'[{0}]'` instead of `'{0}'` or `'({0})'`?

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes there is, not reading the question carefully :D `'{0}'` doesn't work since if the string is multiline. Thanks for noticing. :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming there is a `file.txt` with the following content:

```
(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (-1, -1), (0, -2), (1, -1), (-1, -3)
(-1, 1), (-1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 3),
(2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 4), (5, 5), (7, 5)
```

You can use `literal_eval()` on each line in a loop and extend resulting list:

```
from ast import literal_eval

result = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        result.extend(literal_eval(line.strip()))

print result
```

prints:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (-1, -1), (0, -2), (1, -1), (-1, -3), (-1, 1), (-1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 4), (5, 5), (7, 5)]
```

FYI, [literal_eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is safe:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.

Hope that helps.